# Convert List of Maps to a single Map with VAVR

Tags: java, dictionary, merge, vavr

I'm struggling to reduce a `List` of `Map`s to a single `Map` using [Vavr](https://www.vavr.io/)

```
<List<Map<String, Object>>>
```

to

```
<Map<String, Object>>
```

I tried it with `flatmap`/`reduce`/`merge` but unfortunately with no happy end :-(

Can someone provided an example how to do it with `io.vavr.collection.List`/`io.vavr.collection.Map` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have several options.

For instance, given the following data set (sorry for its simplicity):

```java
Map<String, Object> map1 = HashMap.of("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2");
Map<String, Object> map2 = HashMap.of("key3", "value3", "key4", "value4");
Map<String, Object> map3 = HashMap.of("key5", "value5", "key6", "value6");
List<Map<String, Object>> list = List.of(map1, map2, map3);
```

You can combine the different `Map`s with [`fold`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.vavr/vavr/0.10.4/io/vavr/collection/Foldable.html#fold-T-java.util.function.BiFunction-), for instance:

```java
Map<String, Object> result = list.fold(HashMap.empty(), (m1, m2) -> m1.merge(m2));
```

You can use [`reduce`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.vavr/vavr/0.10.4/io/vavr/collection/Foldable.html#reduce-java.util.function.BiFunction-) as well:

```java
Map<String, Object> result = list.reduce((m1, m2) -> m1.merge(m2));
```

Both of them use the `Map` [`merge`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.vavr/vavr/0.10.3/io/vavr/collection/Map.html#merge-io.vavr.collection.Map-) method. There is an [overloaded version](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.vavr/vavr/0.10.3/io/vavr/collection/Map.html#merge-io.vavr.collection.Map-java.util.function.BiFunction-) of this method that allows you to define how collisions should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what vavr has to do with this.

```
list.stream()                             // A
  .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()) // B
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

[A] Now you have a stream of `Map<String, Object>`.

[B] Now you have a stream of map entries.
Now you have a stream of key/value pairs.

Then just collect them into a map by providing a function to extract a key from a `Map.Entry` object, and a function that extracts a value.

Note that if you have a map of type `Map<String, Object>`, I give it 99% odds you're doing something wrong. Java is nominally, statically, and strongly typed, after all.